# Add web pages to gRPC Service project (VS 2019)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core, grpc

I've created a project of type "gRPC Service C#" in Visual Studio 2019. Can I add (and host) web pages to that project? or should I create another one (and what type of project)?
I want to use these web pages as interface with gRPC services (not call them directly from a web browser). Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's possible by using a Worker but it's a lot of pain. Good practice is having a worker or IIS to host gRPC service and a web application on another project.